# How to use 2 Sums in 1 select statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to get the sums of 2 rows of 2 separate tables in one query.
I tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(Items.Price) AS [Total Items], SUM(Stores.Cash) AS [Total Cash]
FROM Items, Stores
```

However, the query returns the sum of Price * number of stores and total cash in stores * number of items. What went wrong?

Comment: Can you post the table structure ?

Comment: That's happening because when you do `FROM Table1, Table2`, the resultant table is cross-join of the two tables. You need to either group one or more columns, or use sub-query to get sum of 1 table and main query to get sum of another, example `SELECT SUM(Items.Price) AS [Total Items], (SELECT SUM(Stores.Cash) AS [Total Cash]
FROM Stores) FROM Items`

Comment: I wrote the example from top of my head. It might be incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Use this

```SQL
SELECT SUM(Price) AS [Total Items]
     , (SELECT SUM(Cash) AS [Total Cash] FROM Stores)
FROM Items
```